# 2 actions jQuery for one LI, problem with return false

Tags: jquery, return, html-lists, action

Hi i have 2 function for one menu, slide bottom under menu and dynamic load content to div.. I have 2 JS files.. Problem is with slide bottom under menu, this back anytime for this same position (first link) i I change or deleted "return false in first JS" bottom is stop on change link (it's good effect).  How can I unit this codes for good effects?

ONE FOR SLIDE BOTTOM

```
(function($) { $.fn.lavaLamp = function(o) { 

o = $.extend({ fx: "linear", speed: 500, click: function(){} }, o || {});

return this.each(function() {
    var me = $(this), noop = function(){},
        $back = $('<li class="back"><div class="left"></div></li>').appendTo(me),
        $li = $("li", this), curr = $("li.current", this)[0] || $($li[0]).addClass("current")[0];

    $li.not(".back").hover(function() {
        move(this);
    }, noop);

    $(this).hover(noop, function() {
        move(curr);
    });

    $li.click(function(e) {
        setCurr(this);
        return o.click.apply(this, [e, this]);
    });

    setCurr(curr);

    function setCurr(el) {
        $back.css({ "left": el.offsetLeft+"px", "width": el.offsetWidth+"px" });
        curr = el;
    };

    function move(el) {
        $back.each(function() {
            $(this).dequeue(); }
        ).animate({
            width: el.offsetWidth,
            left: el.offsetLeft
        }, o.speed, o.fx);
    };

});
};
})(jQuery);
```

AND SECOND FOR LOAD TO DIV

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
 var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
   var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
   $('#content').load(toLoad)
  }           
 });

 $('#nav li a').click(function(){

  var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
  $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
  $('#load').remove();
  $('#contents').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
  $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
  window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
  function loadContent() {
   $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
  }
  function showNewContent() {
   $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
  }
  function hideLoader() {
   $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
  }
  return false;

 });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `return false` to prevent going to the `href`, use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) which does *only* that and doesn't kill the event, like this:

```
$('#nav li a').click(function(e){ //add event parameter here
  var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
  $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
  $('#load').remove();
  $('#contents').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
  $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
  window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
  function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
  }
  function showNewContent() {
    $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
  }
  function hideLoader() {
    $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```